# mutual non-mutual friend query mysql

Tags: mysql

Hello everyone I have been trying this for ages now.

I have read many questions here and tried adapting the varied solutions to my needs but without results.

History:

for an event there are many participants.
the participants all meet one another at the event and give out "likes" to all the other participants they actually like.

At the end of the event the admin inserts all the likes for each participant of THAT event, and the system will find the mutual likes (friendship)

Problem:
While inserting the likes i would like (pun) the system to detect weather a friendship is already established (from other events also) and if so avoid to display that user name when setting the likes.

Here are the tables that I'm using (mysql)

### wp_fd_users

id | user_name | user_gender | .. etc

### wp_fd_matches

id | event_id | event_user_id | event_user_match_id | ... etc

Example of the match table

```
1 | 1 | 1 | 3 | ...
2 | 1 | 1 | 4 | ...
3 | 1 | 2 | 6 | ...
4 | 1 | 3 | 1 | ...
```

where you can clearly see that 1 <-> 3 have a mutual relationship and 1 likes 4 but not mutually.
I would need a query that returns all results that AVOID relationships that have been established in one single event.

An occurance like this:

```
1 | 1 | 1 | 3 | ...
2 | 1 | 1 | 4 | ...
3 | 1 | 2 | 6 | ...
4 | 2 | 3 | 1 | ...
```

would not trigger the like because it happens in two separate events

Hope it's clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YOur question is a little unclear.  I am going by: "I would need a query that returns all results that AVOID relationships that have been established in one single event."

The following self join accomplishes this:

```
select m1.*
from wp_fd_matches m1 left outer join
     wp_fd_matches m2
     on m1.event_id = m2.event_id and
        m1.event_user_id = m2.event_user_match_id
        m1.event_user_match_id = m2.event_user_id
where m2.id is null
```

It looks for the matching record.  However, by using a left outer join, it is getting all records.  It then filters out the ones with a match.

Comment: Thanks this seems to work properly but is there a way to not get all the records? This is going to be quite a big table and in the future getting loads of results may slow it down.
Also I have to insert this SELECT statement in another SELECT, so just wondering how this would impact performance

Comment: This is the query where I need to insert it into:
    SELECT *, wp_fd_users.id AS userid, wp_fd_users.user_gender AS usergender FROM wp_fd_subscriptions JOIN wp_fd_events ON event_id = wp_fd_events.id JOIN wp_fd_users ON event_user_id = wp_fd_users.id WHERE (wp_fd_subscriptions.event_id = 1 AND wp_fd_users.id != 2 AND wp_fd_users.user_gender != 0) ORDER BY wp_fd_users.user_name;

Comment: Your question was asking for all the records.  Can you rephrase the question to clarify what you want?

Comment: Sure. Thanks for taking the time to answer me.

The query you provided me was a part of the bigger query I wrote later.
What happens is that in the admin I choose an event via a dropdown and immediately another dropdown with a list of participants is created.
When I then select one user from this second dropdown, a list of all participants minus this user himself and those whom he has a mutual friendship already established with, appear in a table each one of them with a checkbox.

Comment: `SELECT *, wp_fd_users.id AS userid, wp_fd_users.user_gender AS usergender
FROM wp_fd_subscriptions
JOIN wp_fd_events ON event_id = wp_fd_events.id
JOIN wp_fd_users ON event_user_id = wp_fd_users.id
WHERE (wp_fd_subscriptions.event_id = 1
AND wp_fd_users.id != 2
AND wp_fd_users.user_gender != 0
) ORDER BY wp_fd_users.user_name;`

Comment: I have created an integration question in the following post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12050062/mutual-friend-sql-integration-complex-query