# mutual friend sql integration complex query

Tags: mysql

History:

for an event there are many participants.
the participants all meet one another at the event and give out "likes" to all the other participants they actually like.

At the end of the event the admin inserts all the likes for each participant of THAT event, and the system will find the mutual likes (friendship)

Problem:
While inserting the likes i would like (pun) the system to detect weather a friendship is already established (from other events also) and if so avoid to display that user name when setting the likes.

Here are the tables that I'm using (mysql)

### wp_fd_users

```
id | user_name | user_gender | ... etc
1  | x         | 0           | ...
2  | y         | 0           | ...
3  | z         | 1           | ...
4  | q         | 1           | ...
```

### wp_fd_subscriptions

```
id | event_id | event_user_id | ...etc
1  | 1        | 1             | ...etc
2  | 1        | 2             | ...etc
3  | 1        | 3             | ...etc
4  | 1        | 4             | ...etc
```

### wp_fd_matches

```
id | event_id | event_user_id | event_user_match_id | ... etc
1  | 1        | 1             | 3                   | ... etc
2  | 1        | 3             | 1                   | ... etc
3  | 1        | 1             | 4                   | ... etc
```

Here is the query that Gordon Linoff kindly gave me to return NON MUTUAL Friends

```
select m1.*
from wp_fd_matches m1 left outer join
     wp_fd_matches m2
     on m1.event_id = m2.event_id and
        m1.event_user_id = m2.event_user_match_id
        m1.event_user_match_id = m2.event_user_id
where m2.id is null
```

Now I need to integrate it in the following query (and optimize it a bit so that this subquery wont return all the records and THEN filter them) - here it is already inserted:

```
SELECT *, wp_fd_users.id AS userid, wp_fd_users.user_gender AS usergender
FROM wp_fd_subscriptions JOIN wp_fd_events ON event_id = wp_fd_events.id
JOIN wp_fd_users ON event_user_id = wp_fd_users.id
WHERE (wp_fd_subscriptions.event_id = 1
  AND wp_fd_users.id != 2 AND wp_fd_users.user_gender != 0
  AND wp_fd_users.id IN (
    select m1.user_event_match_id
    from wp_fd_matches m1 left outer join
    wp_fd_matches m2 on m1.event_id = m2.event_id and
      m1.event_user_id = m2.event_user_match_id and
      m1.event_user_match_id = m2.event_user_id where m2.id is null
    )
)
ORDER BY wp_fd_users.user_name;
```

This would return all the records in the subscription table joined with the user table and the events table.
Specifically what I need to get are all **not already mutual friends of a given user that has participated at a given event**

The sql written above gives me always the same row at the moment.

It seems to avoid any user that has a relationship with any other user

Also if I change the user gender in the query I always get zero results.

**Edit: it is very hard to exactly define what is needed but hopefully I am getting there:
The query must return all users that:
 1. have participated to event 1 even if they have no entry whatsoever in the wp_fd_matches table
 2. Are not the focused user
 3. Do not have a mutual relationship with the focused user in any event**

Link to other discussion is here: [mutual non-mutual friend query mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12038471/mutual-non-mutual-friend-query-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

event_id = 1 and your user id = 1

```
SELECT u.*
FROM wp_fd_subscriptions AS s
JOIN wp_fd_users AS u 
   ON s.event_user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN wp_fd_matches m1 
   ON m1.event_id = s.event_id 
   AND m1.event_user_id = 1
   AND m1.event_user_match_id = s.event_user_id
LEFT JOIN wp_fd_matches m2
   ON m1.event_id = m2.event_id 
   AND m2.event_user_id = m1.event_user_match_id
   AND m2.event_user_match_id = 1
WHERE s.event_id=1 AND u.id != 1 AND m2.id IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is unclear. as u said userid4 shoud come in the resultset

```
SELECT *, wp_fd_users.id AS userid, wp_fd_users.user_gender AS usergender
    FROM wp_fd_subscriptions JOIN wp_fd_events ON event_id = wp_fd_events.id
    JOIN wp_fd_users ON event_user_id = wp_fd_users.id
    WHERE (wp_fd_subscriptions.event_id = 1
      AND wp_fd_users.id != 2 AND wp_fd_users.user_gender != 0
      AND wp_fd_users.id IN (
        select m1.event_user_match_id 
        from wp_fd_matches m1 left outer join
        wp_fd_matches m2 on m1.event_id = m2.event_id and
          m1.event_user_id = m2.event_user_match_id and
          m1.event_user_match_id = m2.event_user_id where m2.id is null
        )
    )
    ORDER BY wp_fd_users.user_name;
```

EDIT::

```
SELECT *, wp_fd_users.id AS userid, wp_fd_users.user_gender AS usergender
FROM wp_fd_subscriptions JOIN wp_fd_events ON event_id = wp_fd_events.id
JOIN wp_fd_users ON event_user_id = wp_fd_users.id
WHERE (wp_fd_subscriptions.event_id = 1
  AND wp_fd_users.id != 2 AND wp_fd_users.user_gender != 0
  AND( wp_fd_users.id IN (
    select m1.user_event_match_id
    from wp_fd_matches m1 left outer join
    wp_fd_matches m2 on m1.event_id = m2.event_id and
      m1.event_user_id = m2.event_user_match_id and
      m1.event_user_match_id = m2.event_user_id where m2.id is null
    ) or NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM wp_fd_matches b 
                       where  wp_fd_users.id =b.user_event_match_id))
)
ORDER BY wp_fd_users.user_name;
```

Comment: i think the "mutual subquery" is not exactly what I need.
I need a query that will return "non-mutual friendship id" AND subscribers that have NO entries in the wp_fd_matches table.